# need help to understand Cauchy-Integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't understand how does $ \epsilon $ come at the end of this formula in [article from Wikipeida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)

\begin{align}
\left | \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-a} \,dz  - f(a) \right |
&= \left | \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a} \,dz \right |\\[.5em]
&\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ |f(z(t)) - f(a)| } {\varepsilon} \,\varepsilon\,dt\\[.5em]
&\leq \max_{|z-a|=\varepsilon}|f(z) - f(a)|
\xrightarrow[\varepsilon\to 0]{} 0.
\end{align}

$$
 \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ |f(z(t)) - f(a)| } {\varepsilon} ,\varepsilon \text{ (<--this epsilon) }\,dt
$$
And also $dz$ is changed in to $dt$ shouldn't there be something to balance it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof defines $z = a + \epsilon e^{it}$ since $z$ is a point on a circular contour of radium $\epsilon$ centered at $a$. Hence, $dz = \epsilon i e^{it} dt$. So the integral's denominator becomes $\epsilon e^{it}$, and this cancels with what we have from the change of variables in the numerator. Also, the $i$ is absorbed by the absolute value sign.